# Capturing the mouse coordinates on every step of a jQuery animation

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, mousemove, mouse-coordinates

I'm trying to get the mouse coordinates during a jQuery animation, I'm doing this because I'm working on an interactive plug-in which moves the background image inside a `div` from `cover`css property to `100%` of it's scale when the user go over the element.

I'm near to completing the `plug-in` but the animation is buggy because it work on the last position of the mouse fired by `mousemove` event of jQuery.

Does exists some way to avoid the problem?

This is my situation:

```
$(settings.selector).hover(function (e) {
    $(this).bind('mousemove', setFollowMouse);
}, function () {
    $(this).unbind('mousemove', setFollowMouse);
    zoomOut();
});

var setFollowMouse = function (e) {
    var o = {offsetLeft:this.offsetLeft, offsetTop:this.offsetTop};
    if (!settings.bg.zooming_in && settings.bg.current_scale != 100) {
    settings.bg.zooming_in = true;
    zoomIn(e, o);
    } else {
        followMouse(e, o);
    }
}

var zoomIn = function (e, o) {

    $({scale:settings.bg.min_perc}).animate ({
        scale:100
    },{
        easing:settings.zoom_in.easing,
        duration:settings.zoom_in.duration,
        step:function () {
            settings.bg.current_scale = this.scale;
            followMouse(e, o);
        },
        complete:function () {
            settings.bg.current_scale = 100;
            settings.bg.zooming_in = false;
            followMouse(e, o);
        }
    });
}

var followMouse = function (e, o) {

    var m_x = e.pageX - o.offsetLeft;
    var m_y = e.pageY - o.offsetTop;

    settings.bg.perc_pos_x = ((m_x * 100) / (a_w - bg_w)) + '%';
    settings.bg.perc_pos_y = ((m_y * 100) / (a_h - bg_h)) + '%';

    var bg_w = getScalePercent(settings.bg.width, settings.bg.current_scale);
    var a_w = settings.container.width;

    var bg_h = getScalePercent(settings.bg.height, settings.bg.current_scale);
    var a_h = settings.container.height;

    var bpx = - (bg_w - a_w) * m_x / a_w;
    var bpy = - (bg_h - a_h) * m_y / a_h;

    $(settings.selector).css({
        backgroundPosition:bpx + 'px ' + bpy + 'px'
        ,backgroundSize:bg_w + 'px ' + bg_h + 'px'
    });
}
```

As you see, I use animation to calculate the progressive scaling of the background-image, and trying to calculating it with the follow mouse method, but if I sto moving the mouse, the animation works with the last `mousemove` `event.pageX` and `Y` mouse position.

I've done this because I have problems with make animation method fluid if I trying to rewrite it continuously by with the mouse.

Should I follow some different way to avoid the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the problem with this simple edit to my code:

```
var setFollowMouse = function (e) {

    settings.mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    settings.mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if (!settings.bg.zooming_in && settings.bg.current_scale != 100) {
        settings.bg.zooming_in = true;
        zoomIn();
    } else {
        followMouse();
    }
}
```

the old one:

```
var setFollowMouse = function (e) {

    var o = {offsetLeft:this.offsetLeft, offsetTop:this.offsetTop};

    if (!settings.bg.zooming_in && settings.bg.current_scale != 100) {
        settings.bg.zooming_in = true;
        zoomIn(e, o);
    } else {
        followMouse(e, o);
    }
}
```

this has removed the buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

forgive my dodgy math; but this should help!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          window.onload = function () {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/23/Autumn_Theme_-_Windows_7_Backgrounds.jpg';

                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var scale = 0.9;

                var scaledwidth = canvas.width * scale;
                var scaledheight = canvas.height * scale;

                var scaledcenterX = scaledwidth /2;
                var scaledcenterY = scaledheight /2;

                var animloop = setInterval(function() {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, scaledwidth, scaledheight, canvas.width - scaledcenterX, canvas.height - scaledcenterY, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }, .01);

                function onMouseMove(e) {
                    mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                    mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                    scale = mouseX/1000;
                    scaledwidth = canvas.width * scale;
                    scaledheight = canvas.height * scale;                    
                }

            };

        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #001;
                background-size: cover;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #canvas1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100% auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really would like to work with canvas, for now I prefere to complete the path of the `jQuery plug-in` I've started because now is finished!